# Where do I run initialisation code when starting a flutter app?

Tags: flutter

Where do I run initialisation code when starting a flutter app?

```
void main() {

  return runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: "My Flutter App",

    theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: globals.AFI_COLOUR_PINK,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white),

        home: RouteSplash(),

    ));
}
```

If I want to run some initialisation code to, say fetch shared preferences, or (in my case) initialise a package (and I need to pass in the the BuildContext of the MaterialApp widget), what is the correct way to do this?

Should I wrap the MaterialApp in a FutureBuilder? Or is there a more 'correct' way?

------- EDIT ---------------------------------------------------

I have now placed the initialisation code in `RouteSplash()` widget. But since I required the BuildContext of the app root for the initialisation, I called the initialisation in the Widget `build` override and passed in `context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(MaterialApp)`. As I don't need to wait for initialisation to complete before showing the splash screen, I haven't used a `Future`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One simple way of doing this will be calling the `RouteSplash` as your splash screen and inside it perform the initialization code as shown.

```
class RouteSplash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RouteSplashState createState() => _RouteSplashState();
}

class _RouteSplashState extends State<RouteSplash> {
  bool shouldProceed = false;

  _fetchPrefs() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));// dummy code showing the wait period while getting the preferences
    setState(() {
      shouldProceed = true;//got the prefs; set to some value if needed
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchPrefs();//running initialisation code; getting prefs etc.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: shouldProceed
            ? RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //move to next screen and pass the prefs if you want
                },
                child: Text("Continue"),
              )
            : CircularProgressIndicator(),//show splash screen here instead of progress indicator
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

and inside the `main()`

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: RouteSplash(),
  ));
}
```

Note: It is just one way of doing it. You could use a `FutureBuilder` if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's always appreciated when someone takes the time to provide a thorough answer. What I have actually done is similar to your answer. Placing initialising code in `RouteSplash()`, but since I needed the `BuildContext` of the app root, I called my equivalent of `_fetchPrefs` in the `build` override and passed in `context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(MaterialApp)`. I'm considering making that asyncronous, but I don't think I need to wait for it to complete before showing the splash screen.

Answer (score -3):

To run code at startup, put it in your main.dart. Personally, that's the way I do it, to initialise lists etc.

Comment: At that point I haven't created any widgets, therefore I don't have a BuildContext for my base widget

Comment: Put everything in main.dart is not recommended.